# extract a link from a web page with python

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I'm writing a code in which it sends the site's link in a chat (I know how to do this part), I make the request, but in this request it returns other things along with the link, how do I get only the link?

```
link = requests.get(f"https://sugoi-api.herokuapp.com/episode/{Episodio}/{AnimeN}")

resultado = link.json()
```

this is the result:

```
{'status': 200, 'info': {'name': 'Naruto classico', 'slug': 'naruto-classico', 'fc': 'N', 'epi': '12'}, 'cdn': [{'name': 'Superanimes', 'url': 'https://cdn.superanimes.tv/', 'links': ['https://cdn.superanimes.tv/010/animes/n/naruto-classico-dublado/12.mp4', 'https://cdn.superanimes.tv/010/animes/n/naruto-classico-legendado/12.mp4%27]%7D, {'name': 'Serverotaku', 'url': 'https://cdn.serverotaku01.co/', 'links': ['https://cdn.serverotaku01.co/010/animes/n/naruto-classico-dublado/12.mp4', 'https://cdn.serverotaku01.co/010/animes/n/naruto-classico-legendado/12.mp4%27]%7D, {'name': 'Servertv', 'url': 'https://servertv001.com/', 'links': ['https://servertv001.com/animes/n/naruto-classico-dublado/12.mp4', 'https://servertv001.com/animes/n/naruto-classico-legendado/12.mp4%27]%7D]%7D
```

if someone knows how to get only the result link it would help me a lot

Comment: Which link do you want to extract? There are several in the response.

Comment: Please provide the exact `website url` or  `json data`!

Comment: the links change all the time, so there's no way to know what ink to pay, what I want is a way to get only ONE of these various links ending in .mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to extract URL from any data (general) is mentioned below. First, Convert the json output you got into a string and then use regular expression.

```
str = json.dumps({'status': 200, 'info':........})
import re
re.findall("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", str)
```